# Dúvida com "return" em funções (java)

Tags: java

Estou com uma dúvida básica com o seguinte código:

```
    public static float calcularMediaAlturaHomens (float TotalAlturaHomens, int NumeroHomens) {
         if (NumeroHomens == 0) {
             return "Sem média!";
         }
         return TotalAlturaHomens / NumeroHomens;
    }
```

Explicação: O meu programa tem uma função que calcula a média da altura de todos os homens (total das alturas / numero de homens) (segundo return), eu também gostaria que se não tivesse homens cadastrados, ele iria retornar "SEM MÉDIA" (primeiro return), mas obviamente da o erro de que eu devo retornar um valor FLOAT, e não string pois a função foi criada em float.(float calcularMediaAlturaHomens).

Dúvida: Como eu retornaria uma String dentro de uma função em float?

Comment: É uma sugestão pois não responde a pergunta *"Como eu retornaria uma String dentro de uma função em float?"*.  Retorne [`Double.NAN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN) e a porção do código responsável por exibir o resultado que interprete-o auxiliado por [Double.isNaN()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN()).

Comment: @AugustoVasques é mais fácil retornar *-1* no caso dele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O fato é se você determinou um tipo de retorno isso precisa ser atendido, é uma regra do Java, pelo menos até onde eu sei. pode até ser burlado como vou mostrar mas não é interessante.

O cenário que eu vejo mais ideal seria você fazer essa comparação na execução de sua aplicação e ou ter um metodo de controle separado, alguns cenários possíveis seriam.

[EDITADO]
outro cenário possível ssería declarar uma classe e por sua vez, trabalhar com os retornos de atributos dessa classe, o codigo foi acrescentado posteriormente.

```
public class Main {
    
    public static String calcularMediaAlturaHomens (float TotalAlturaHomens, int NumeroHomens) {
        if (NumeroHomens == 0) {
            return "Sem média!";
        }
        return ""+ TotalAlturaHomens / NumeroHomens;
    }
    static float media = 0F;
    public static void calcularMediaAlturaHomens2 (float TotalAlturaHomens, int NumeroHomens) {
         media = TotalAlturaHomens / NumeroHomens;
    }
    
    public static float calcularMediaAlturaHomen3 (float TotalAlturaHomens, int NumeroHomens) {
        return TotalAlturaHomens / NumeroHomens;
    }
// outra forma seria declarar ua classe para retorno
    public static MinhaClasseDeRetorno calcularMediaAlturaHomen4(float TotalAlturaHomens, int NumeroHomens) {
        MinhaClasseDeRetorno mcr = new MinhaClasseDeRetorno();
        if (NumeroHomens == 0) {
            mcr.message="Sem média!";
        }
        mcr.media = TotalAlturaHomens / NumeroHomens;
        return mcr;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        // caso um, retorne String mesmo
        System.out.println(calcularMediaAlturaHomens(200, 2));
        
        // retorne para uma variável de classe, poderia ser um atributo
        // ou metodo de retorno.
        calcularMediaAlturaHomens2(0, 2);
        System.out.println(media > 0 ? media : "Sem média!");
        
        // atribua o retorno em tempo de execução
        float media1 = calcularMediaAlturaHomen3(0, 2);
        System.out.println(media1 > 0 ? media1 : "Sem média!");

        // retorno a partir de uma classe, com comportamento em atributos
        System.out.println(calcularMediaAlturaHomen4(100,2));
        System.out.println(calcularMediaAlturaHomen4(0,2));
    }
}

class MinhaClasseDeRetorno {
    String message = "";
    float media = 0F;
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public float getMedia() {
        return media;
    }
    public void setMedia(float media) {
        this.media = media;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return media > 0 ? ""+ media : message;
    }
}
```

no exemplo acima fiz trêz funções simples onde uma retorna uma string, outra não tem retorno e outra retorna o float, cada uma com pequenas características.

Comment: Não teria como eu criar um function sem declarar seu tipo primitivo? Assim ela iria retorna o valor em String ou int de acordo com os resultados.

Comment: @DaviRibeiro.  Não é possível Java é uma linguagem fortemente tipificada ou seja o tipo dum objeto deve estar disponível(declarado) em tempo de compilação senão a fonte não é compilada. A característica que procura só está presente em linguagens fracamente tipificadas como Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Você provavelmente brincou com outra linguagem(javascript, php, python) as quais não são fortemente tipadas e então veio para Java.

Em Java, isso que você quer fazer não é possível, porém, existe uma maneira de fazer isso.

Como em Java, tudo é objeto, você poderá criar uma instância de qualquer objeto e retornar está instância, porém é uma péssima prática.

```
 public static Object calcularMediaAlturaHomens (float TotalAlturaHomens, int NumeroHomens) {
     if (NumeroHomens == 0) {
         return "Sem média!";
     }
     return TotalAlturaHomens / NumeroHomens;
 }


 public static void main(String []args){
     
    final Object resultado1 = calcularMediaAlturaHomens(1.84F, 2);
    final Object resultado2 = calcularMediaAlturaHomens(1.84F, 0);
    
    if( resultado1 instanceof Float) {
        float valor = (float)resultado1;
        System.out.println(valor);
    }
    

    if( resultado2 instanceof String ) {
        System.out.printf("É uma string: %s.\n", resultado2.toString());
    }  
 }
```

O correto, seria você retornar uma *Exception(própria de preferência)* o que é um erro.
Porque, analise o contexto, você precisa de homens para calcular, se não têm homens, não é possível realizar o cálculo.

```
public static float calcularMediaAlturaHomens (float TotalAlturaHomens, int NumeroHomens) {
     if (NumeroHomens == 0) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sem média!");
     }
     return TotalAlturaHomens / NumeroHomens;
}


 public static void main(String []args){
    
    float a = calcularMediaAlturaHomens(1.31F, 12);
    System.out.printf("Média: %f.\n", a);
    
    float b = calcularMediaAlturaHomens(1.31F, 0); // o método irá lançar o erro, você faz o que precisa ser feito.
    
 }
```

Contudo, uma outra maneira, mais fácil e menos custosa ao Sisop, seria retornar um número negativo.

Pelo nome dos seus parâmetros, você nunca terá um número negativo(*Positivo / positivo = positivo*).
Então, você pode retornar ***-1*** quando `numeroHomens == 0`;

```
public static float calcularMediaAlturaHomens (float TotalAlturaHomens, int NumeroHomens) {
     if (NumeroHomens == 0) {
         return -1F;
     }
     return TotalAlturaHomens / NumeroHomens;
}

public static void main(String []args){

    float a = calcularMediaAlturaHomens(1.31F, 12);
    System.out.printf("Média: %f.\n", a);

    float b = calcularMediaAlturaHomens(1.31F, 0);
    if(b == -1F) { /** sem média */  }


 }
```

Comment: Ainda poderia retornar um `Float` em vez de `float` e poder ser nulo, considero melhor que retornar um negativo, ainda que para este caso funcione. E ainda poderia usar um `Optional` https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html. Criar uma classe só para isto parece um canhão para matar passarinho e retornar `Object` realmente fica como curiosidade, não é uma boa idea. Quase não positivei porque essa ideia de "em Java tudo é objeto" está errado por vários pontos de visto.